# isometry group of an integer $n$ as of the corresponding $\Omega(n)$-parallelotope

Tags: number-theory, finite-groups

Let $\prod_{i\in I}p_{i}^{a_{i}}$ be the prime factorization of a positive integer $n$ and let's consider the $\Omega(n)$-parallelotope built with, for all $i\in I$, $a_{i}$ pairwise orthogonal vectors of norm $p_{i}$, so that there are $\omega(n)$ different lengths for the sides of this parallelotope. Let's consider the isometry group of this parallelotope, as a part of the affine space $\mathbb{R}^{\Omega(n)}$, denoted by $G(n)$.

Can this group provide information of arithmetical interest about $n$?

Thanks in advance.